# Set $_SESSION to expire in 1 month PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-timeout

I am trying to get my $_SESSIONS to expire in 30 days. I do not deal with any sensitive data on my server, so I am not worried about cookie hi-jacking. Would this work?

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2592000); 
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 2592000);
session_start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to your cookie, there are some other settings you need to look at in your php.ini.

You can manipulate them in code as follows:

```
// Current Session Timeout Value
$currentTimeout= ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');

// Change session timeout value for a particular page load  - 1 month = ~2678400 seconds
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 2678400);
```

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes) and [here](http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/manually-set-php-session-timeout-php-session/)

Comment: Please note that PHP does not support `’` as string delimiter.